# Get CloudQueueMessage in Windows Azure worker role throws IO Exception in Azure Emulator

Tags: asp.net, azure, registry, ioexception

As can be seen from the image below I'm doing a pretty standard bit of code in a Worker Role to get a message from a queue in Azure Storage but it's throwing this IOException with text saying **the specified registry key does not exist**.

```
    CloudQueueMessage message = queue.GetMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

is the code that's causing the problem, sometimes it works fine or other times it doesn't. Very strange.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set your Local Config file Connection String to use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`

From a quick google, this error can crop up as well if you have a mis-match between the 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient (v1.7) and the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (v2.0) libraries referenced in your application.

Comment: Thanks, the local config file is set to UseDevelopmentStorage=false.

Comment: I did have references to StorageClient but removing them and rebuilding made no difference unfortunately. It works when I deploy to Azure though!

Comment: The only other thing I can think then is that you have a corrupted/incorrect registry key security setting. The CloudQueueMessage class is basically just a wrapper around a HTTP Web Request to a rest endpoint. It could be trying to access information about the local proxy or a bunch of other things and then failing to read the key. Best I can suggest is to grab the source and step into it to see exactly where it's failing. does the full stack trace give a key name from the registry that it's failing on ?

Comment: After hours of digging it seems it might have been a rogue NUGET package that was causing an exception using the HTTP Web Request. Very frustrating, thanks for your help.